# Найти сумму элементов заданной строки матрицы

Tags: visual-basic

Помогите пожалуйста, хоть с 0 написать, очень хочу чистого и простого логичного кода, отставьте комментарии по коду, буду очень благодарен !)

```
 Dim i, j
    Dim text, answer
    Dim m As Byte, n As Byte, sum As Integer
    Dim a() As Integer
    n = InputBox("N")
    m = InputBox("M")
    ReDim a(1 To n, 1 To m) As Integer
    For i = 1 To n
    sum = 0
    For j = 1 To m
    a(i, j) = Int((100) * Rnd - 50)
    sum = sum + a(i, j)
    text = text & a(i, j) & Space(3)
    Next j
    answer = answer & "Номер строки : " & i & "  Сумма:  " & sum & vbLf
    text = text & vbLf
    Next i
    MsgBox text
    MsgBox answer
```

Comment: Ваш код: Для каждой строки i вначале заполняет каждый элемент массива случайным значением от -50 до 50; тут же суммирует это значение с переменной sum; А при переходе к строке i+1 у вас ошибка: Должно быть text = text & answer  & vbLf

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        'Для матрицы A (n, n) найти сумму элементов заданной строки
        Dim sum As Integer, Ns As Integer
        Ns = InputBox("Введите номер строки", "Подсчет суммы в строке", 1)
        If Ns < n Then
            For i = 0 To n - 1
                sum = sum + DataGridView1.Item(i, Ns).Value
            Next
            TextBox1.Text = sum
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "Заданной строки в матрице не найдено !!!"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class